# Oracle - json data contains array/string interchangeably

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c

I have json data and I am trying to put that data in different columns in oracle. 
Issue is one of the column sometimes contains an array and sometimes contain string. 
I know there is different command to put json array to column but if the column is populated with string sometimes and array sometimes, how do I write sql so that it fetch all data -

```
SELECT id,array1
FROM   (
  select '{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "array1": [ "INFO", "ABC", ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "array1": "TEST",
      }
    ]
  }' AS JSON_DATA
  FROM DUAL
) I,
json_table(
  i.JSON_DATA ,
  '$.data[*]'  
  COLUMNS (
    array1 varchar2(4000) FORMAT JSON path'$."array1"',
    ID     varchar2(4000) path '$."id"'
  )  
) a
```

Output from the sql:

```
ID  ARRAY1
1   ["INFO","ABC"]
2
```

Desired Ouput :

```
ID  ARRAY1
1   ["INFO","ABC"]
2   TEST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array1 varchar2(4000) PATH '$."array1"'` can be considered together with

`array1 varchar2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$."array1"'`

Since both case exists for values of `array1` key. So, use :

```
SELECT ID, NVL(array1, array1_) AS array1
  FROM   
  (
   SELECT '{
        "data": [

          {
            "id": 1,
            "array1": [ "INFO", "ABC" ]
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "array1": "TEST"
          }
        ]
      }' AS JSON_DATA
     FROM DUAL
     ) I
    CROSS JOIN 
    JSON_TABLE(
      i.JSON_DATA ,
      '$.data[*]'  
      COLUMNS (
           array1  varchar2(4000) PATH '$."array1"',
           array1_ varchar2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$."array1"',
           ID      varchar2(4000) PATH '$."id"'
      )  
     ) A
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f03dddd4bd70d2dddeeee55485ef3eb0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks !! I was also thinking same. was wondering is there any alternate than to do nvl